# How to refine a parameter's type depending on another parameter's value in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to refine a parameter's type dependending on another parameter's value in TypeScript without using discriminated unions.

Here is an example of code that I want to typecheck :

```js
enum Operation { add = 'add', sub = 'sub', mul = 'mul', div = 'div', cos = 'cos' }
type OperationData = {
    add: { lhs: number, rhs: number };
    sub: { lhs: number, rhs: number };
    mul: { lhs: number, rhs: number };
    div: { lhs: number, rhs: number };
    cos: { value: number };
}
function calc<O extends Operation>(op: O, data: OperationData[O]): number {
    switch (op) {
        case Operation.add:
            return data.lhs + data.rhs;
        case Operation.sub:
            return data.lhs - data.rhs;
        case Operation.mul:
            return data.lhs * data.rhs;
        case Operation.div:
            return data.lhs / data.rhs;
        case Operation.cos:
            return Math.cos(data.value);
    }
}
console.log(calc(Operation.add, {lhs: 1, rhs: 2})); //=> 3
```

Right now, only the usage of `calc()` typechecks, and its implementation does not.

For reference, here are the typechecking errors :

```
    Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.
    Property 'lhs' does not exist on type 'OperationData[O]'.
    Property 'rhs' does not exist on type 'OperationData[O]'.
    Property 'lhs' does not exist on type 'OperationData[O]'.
    Property 'rhs' does not exist on type 'OperationData[O]'.
    Property 'lhs' does not exist on type 'OperationData[O]'.
    Property 'rhs' does not exist on type 'OperationData[O]'.
    Property 'lhs' does not exist on type 'OperationData[O]'.
    Property 'rhs' does not exist on type 'OperationData[O]'.
    Property 'value' does not exist on type 'OperationData[O]'.
```

https://tsplay.dev/3ND8ON

Answer (score 0):

Right now it's not possible to narrow generic types in switch cases. The thing you can do which is slightly less elegant but still better than discriminated unions is using `type assertions`.

```
function calc<O extends Operation>(op: O, data: OperationData[O]): number {
    let typeCheckedData;
    switch (op) {
        case Operation.add:
            typeCheckedData = data as OperationData[Operation.add]
            return typeCheckedData.lhs + typeCheckedData.rhs;
        case Operation.sub:
            typeCheckedData = data as OperationData[Operation.sub]
            return typeCheckedData.lhs - typeCheckedData.rhs;
        case Operation.mul:
            typeCheckedData = data as OperationData[Operation.mul]
            return typeCheckedData.lhs * typeCheckedData.rhs;
        case Operation.div:
            typeCheckedData = data as OperationData[Operation.div]
            return typeCheckedData.lhs / typeCheckedData.rhs;
        case Operation.cos:
            typeCheckedData = data as OperationData[Operation.cos]
            return Math.cos(typeCheckedData.value);
    }
}
```

The thing that I thought TS is intelligent enough to understand was below simple control-flow narrowing but unfortunately it didn't work, so the above solution is *I think* your best bet.

```
 switch (op) {
    case Operation.add:
           typeCheckedData = data as OperationData[typeof op]
           return typeCheckedData.lhs + typeCheckedData.rhs;
 ....
```